# How to get id of submit type button, when button is pressed

Tags: php, html

I want to print out the id of the button I pressed. The id is set dynamically for each button in a table. This is my HTML code:

```
    echo '<td><center><input type="submit" id="'.$row['I_ID'].'" class="btn"
name="Add" value ="Add to cart"><center></td><tr>';
```

And I want to print the id of the button here.

```
if (isset($_POST['Add'])) {
    $ID = $_GET['id'];
    echo $ID;
    echo '<br/>' . "* The item has been added to your cart.";
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you do not wish to use a hidden field, you could set your submit button like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="id" value="value">Submit</button>
```

Then you can catch it with `$_GET['id']`.

You can have many buttons of `type="submit"` with the same name (`id`), and the value will be the one which was clicked, or the first one, if the form was submitted by pressing enter.

Comment: That's a great idea. Thanks for sharing it with me, it's just what I needed.

Comment: Note: It's not advisable to put important form data in a button.  You really should use the hidden input.

Comment: @TheSmose Are there any compatibility issues or something else I'm not aware of? I've used this approach quite a lot, and I haven't found issues with any of the modern browsers.

Comment: @Pinetree, no big ones that I'm aware of.  The little one is that the `button` element was a newer addition to HTML (HTML 4, I think?) so it's not supported by older browsers (IE4, NS4, etc.) However, it's a convention to use hidden inputs for form data, likely dating back to the days when the `input type="submit"` was all that was available for buttons.

Answer (score 4):

The 'id' attribute doesn't submit to PHP, only the 'value' attribute submits.

What you should do is add a hidden input with the name "id", like this:

```
echo '<td><center><input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row['I_ID'] . '" /><input type="submit" id="'.$row['I_ID'].'" class="btn" name="Add" value ="Add to cart"><center></td><tr>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" value=".$row['I_ID']." name="input2"/>
```

Then access it in the second script through:

```
$_POST['input2']; // or $_GET['input2'], depending on the method of the form submitting
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the id attribute is not passed to PHP.

You can use the name attribute instead of id and it will get passed to PHP.

If you have the following HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="some_name" class="btn" value ="Add to cart">
```

The you can access it in PHP as

```
$_POST['some_name'] = "Add to Cart"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the id with jquery and send it via ajax call:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input.btn', function() {
    var this_id = $(this).attr('id');
    ajaxCall(this_id);
});

function ajaxCall(this_id) {
    var data = 'id=' + this_id;

$.ajax({
    url: 'proccess.php',  
    type: "GET",    
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
            DO WHAT EVER YOU WANT WITH THE RETURNED html
    }         
});
```

Your 'proccess.php':

```
    if (isset($_POST['Add'])) {
        $ID = $_GET['id'];
        echo $ID;
        echo '<br/>' . "* The item has been added to your cart.";
    }
```