# Multi-submit buttons on one form with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a form which has 5 submit buttons like

```
<form action="pages/test.php" method="post" name="form1 "onsubmit="ajaxrequest('pages/test.php', 'resp'); return false;">
    <input type="hidden" name="Id" id ="Id" value=<?php echo "{$Id}"; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="Value" value="0.01" />
    <input type="submit" name="Value" value="0.02" />
    <input type="submit" name="Value" value="0.03" />
    <input type="submit" name="Value" value="0.04" />
    <input type="submit" name="Value" value="0.05" />
</form>

<div id="resp">Here will be displayed the server response.</div><br />
```

The ajax processing for this is:

```
function get_XmlHttp() {
    var xmlHttp = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return xmlHttp;
}

// sends data to a php file, via POST, and displays the received answer
function ajaxrequest(php_file, tagID) {
    var request =  get_XmlHttp();
    var Id = document.getElementById('Id').value;
    var Value = document.getElementById('Value').value;

    // create pairs index=value with data that must be sent to server
    var  the_data = 'Id='+Id+'&Value='+Value;

    request.open("POST", php_file, true);

    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(the_data);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById(tagID).innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

The test.php is:
    `$Id = strip_tags($_POST['Id']); $Value = strip_tags($_POST['Value']); echo "{$Id}, {$Value}";`

The problem is that when clicking on any value in the form only the first value is ever displayed. How do I get it to recognise all the different submit values?

Answer (score 0):

When posting, only the last value of the same name will be changed.
See this post [on using multiple name elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203430/posting-form-fields-with-same-name-attribute)

What you are looking for is something like this [where you have multiple button names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578002/get-id-of-button-once-clicked-using-php).

If you need to loop through them, give them predictable names then loop through the names like:

```
Submit1
Submit2
Submit3
```

EDIT:

You are getting the element by `getElementByID('Value')`

This will get the first element with the ID value.

This may be a good way to go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can call them submit1, submit2 etc but not sure how to code it within the Ajax